# How pass references to nested shared data between threads?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a function which returns a Vec containing pairs which match a certain criteria.

```rust
fn find<'a>(slice1: &[&'a TypeA], slice2: &[&'a TypeB]) -> Vec<(&'a TypeA, &'a TypeB)>;
```

I can't simply use filter of `Iterator` because the results aren't independent of each other.

Now I want to call this function inside an Iced [command](https://docs.rs/iced/latest/iced/struct.Command.html), which essentially means from an async context.

When I try to use RwLocks this does not work because a and b are dropped while the reference created by the call to find still exist.

```rust
enum Message {
    Found(Vec<(&'static TypeA, &'static TypeB)>),
    //...
}
//...
fn update(&mut self, message: Self::Message) -> Command<Self::Message>{
//...
    Command::perform( async {
        let a = self.a_rw_lock.read().unwrap();
        let b = self.b_rw_lock.read().unwrap();
        find(&a,&b) //cannot return value referencing temporary value
    }, |x| Message::Found(x))
//...
}
```

I would like to try to solve this without cloning the underlying data as it can get quite large. Also it would be preferable if I don't have to change the signature of find.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible, the lock guard can't cross thread boundaries, which means any reference belongs to the future and can't move out of it, because references are only valid as long as the lock is held. So you have to either restructure your system, or return something like a vector of indices / index pairs such that the caller is able to take ownership of the indices and use that to fetch the items. Even with lock projections (e.g. from parking lot) I don't think it can work, because the guard still needs to cross thread boundaries. And scoped futures aren't a thing.

Comment: As is this question is missing way too much detail. Can you include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? My best guess, without knowing more about your program, is that `Self::Message` MUST somehow erase the lifetimes, which is to say, it must hold a ref counted data which owns the underlying references. You can define such types in many ways, e.g. [yoke](https://docs.rs/yoke/latest/yoke/). Otherwise you would have to `mem::take` from `self.a_rw_lock` and move that into the closure.